# In this situation would the system have linear momentum after the collision?

Tags: angular-momentum, momentum

A puck hits a stick at one of the ends (the ball moves perpendicular to the stick) on a horizontal surface. The stick is fixed in place with a pin at its center and free to rotate. There is no friction. After the collision, the puck sticks to the stick and the system rotates. Would this system have linear momentum after the collision? My thoughts are the center of mass would not be at the axis of rotation, therefore it would move as the system rotates.

Comment: There is a constraint force by the pin at the centre. This would cancel out any linear force.

Comment: You are correct, the CoM of the puck+stick system is NOT at the center and hence there is motion of the CoM.  Because of the constraint it will be uniform circular motion.